# change table column width

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm using react library that constructs table in the following template:

```
    <div class="table-container" style="width:100%">
    <table style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>BLA_Column</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>BLA_Body</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I'm able to set the width of the th and the td to auto, but, the result is that I get two different sizes (one for the th and one for the td).
When I try to use the following selector (for example), nothing happens:

```
table > thead > th {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Also when I try to change directly the width using the chrome dev-tools, there is no change at all.

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Maybe you could consider changing the table to be a css `flex` object, or the table container

Comment: i think you have something wrong in your css selector `table > thead > th`

... `th` is not a direct descendant (`>`) of `thead`

Comment: I think the problem is table `width: 100%` - `th` is `display: table-cell` - change it to some other value, like `inline-block`. See here -> http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/wJKrXp

Answer (score 1):

CSS character > select only direct childs. Change your CSS with :

```
table > thead th {
    width: 100px;
}
```

or

```
table > thead > tr > th {
    width: 100px;
}
```